# JavaEE Application Client Remote Injection problems

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, java-ee-7, initial-context

Every time I deploy the client app after deploying the ejb I at random get `@EJB` injection errors, sometimes it's with `ShipFacade`, sometimes it's something else, either an injection before or after this one, it seems like it's more or less at random.
Consecutive deployment without changing any code produces this kind of behavior.
The stacktrace is just the recent one I got before I decided to post it.

Would greatly appreciate any help.

***NOTE:*** This is my first time working with the Enterprise Client Application module, so any and all useful advice is greatly appreciated.

SessionBean:

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "ShipFacadeRemote")
@PermitAll
public class ShipFacade extends AbstractFacade<Ship> implements ShipFacadeLocal, ShipFacadeRemote {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "Port-ejbPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public ShipFacade() {
        super(Ship.class);
    }
}
```

Remote Interface:

```
@Remote
public interface ShipFacadeRemote {

    void create(Ship stock);

    void edit(Ship stock);

    void remove(Ship stock);

    Ship find(Object id);

    List<Ship> findAll();

    List<Ship> findRange(int[] range);

    int count();
}
```

Local Interface:

```
@Local
public interface ShipFacadeLocal {

    void create(Ship stock);

    void edit(Ship stock);

    void remove(Ship stock);

    Ship find(Object id);

    List<Ship> findAll();

    List<Ship> findRange(int[] range);

    int count();
}
```

Enterprise Client Application:

```
public class Main {
    .
    .
    .
    @EJB(mappedName = "ShipFacadeRemote")
    private static ShipFacadeRemote shipFacade;
    .
    .
    .

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

}
```

Stacktrace:

```
com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=portclient.Main/shipFacade,Remote 3.x interface =beans.ShipFacadeRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=ShipFacadeRemote,jndi-name=ShipFacadeRemote,refType=Session into class portclient.Main: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/portclient.Main/shipFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl}
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:740)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:507)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectClass(InjectionManagerImpl.java:235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectClass(InjectionManagerImpl.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer$ClientMainClassSetting.getClientMainClass(AppClientContainer.java:636)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.getMainMethod(AppClientContainer.java:525)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.completePreparation(AppClientContainer.java:419)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.prepare(AppClientContainer.java:320)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.prepareACC(AppClientFacade.java:279)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.agent.AppClientContainerAgent.premain(AppClientContainerAgent.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/portclient.Main/shipFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=portclient.Main/shipFacade,Remote 3.x interface =beans.ShipFacadeRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=ShipFacadeRemote,jndi-name=ShipFacadeRemote,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'ShipFacadeRemote#beans.ShipFacadeRemote' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'ShipFacadeRemote#beans.ShipFacadeRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ShipFacadeRemote#beans.ShipFacadeRemote not found]]]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:636)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=portclient.Main/shipFacade,Remote 3.x interface =beans.ShipFacadeRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=ShipFacadeRemote,jndi-name=ShipFacadeRemote,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'ShipFacadeRemote#beans.ShipFacadeRemote' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'ShipFacadeRemote#beans.ShipFacadeRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ShipFacadeRemote#beans.ShipFacadeRemote not found]]
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:188)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$EjbReferenceProxy.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:1015)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:745)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:715)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:159)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:471)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'ShipFacadeRemote#beans.ShipFacadeRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ShipFacadeRemote#beans.ShipFacadeRemote not found]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:183)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ShipFacadeRemote#beans.ShipFacadeRemote not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:237)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:204)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:66)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.RemoteSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(RemoteSerialContextProviderImpl.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie.dispatchToMethod(ReflectiveTie.java:143)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:173)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1549)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(MessageMediatorImpl.java:930)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:213)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:694)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.doWork(MessageMediatorImpl.java:2222)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Try removing the `mappedName` attribute from all of your `@EJB` annotations (but keep the annotations themselves, of course).

Comment: Removing the `mappedName` (from all `@EJB` notations) while keeping the `@EJB` annotations produces the same exception but on a different injected variable, following the previously mentioned random behavior.